# How does bash search for program if command is a result from subprocess program

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I was just playing around a minute a ago in *zsh*, and I ran this and got confused

```sh
`echo ls`
```

it returned the stork `ls` result(I had ls an aliase in my .zshrc), no coloring, no sorting.

I thought the ls is just text returned from a *non-interactive* sub-shell, and the text should be ran as a interactive shell command in the current shell. Why wasn't it using my alias?

I tried this in *bash*, it's the same result. I wonder how shell actually search for commands in this case.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that aliases are not commands. They are essentially simple parse-time prefix substitutions.

This means that they only apply when the command *as entered* starts with the alias text (i.e. *not* as executed, just as entered):

```
ls   # Uses ls alias because it starts with ls
\ls  # No alias. It executes ls but starts with \l
"ls" # No alias. It executes ls but starts with "l
`echo ls` # No alias. It executes ls but starts with `e
```

If you'd like a customized command that applies *as executed* and not just as entered, use a function:

```
ls() { command ls --myflags "$@"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [the excellent answer by that other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55369497/2072269), normal aliases in zsh don't apply to the output of command substitution or variable expansion when run as a command, or to normal text that appears after the command name (like options and arguments). *Global* aliases, however, still affect the text after the command name. So, for example, if `ls` were a global alias to `ls --color`, `` `echo ls` `` could become `` `echo ls --color` ``:

```
$ alias -g ls='ls -1rt'
$ `echo ls`
opt
installer.failurerequests
System
...
$ echo `echo ls`
ls -1rt
```

This makes [global aliases](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_8.html) very risky to use:

> The last example shows one of the perils of global aliases; they have
>   a lot of potential to cause confusion. For example, if you defined a
>   global alias called `|` (which is possible), zsh would begin to act
>   very strangely; every pipe symbol would be replaced with the text of
>   your alias. To some extent, global aliases are like macros in C;
>   discretion is advised in using them and in choosing names for them.